# Splash Screen not loading in app

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have added the code for a splash screen for a loading page in an android app, but nothing has changed, can anybody solve this??

This is my code:

```
Thread splashThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           try {
              int waited = 0;
              while (waited < 1000) {
                 sleep(100);
                 waited += 100;
              }
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              // do nothing
           } finally {

              Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this,Activity1.class);

              startActivity(i);
              finish();
           }
        }
     };
     splashThread.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use  [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for starting activity from seprate Thread as:

```
 Splash.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                  // some code #3 (that needs to be ran in UI thread)
                  Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this,Activity1.class);

                 startActivity(i);
                 finish();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code below:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

        // run a thread after 2 seconds to start the home screen
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                // make sure we close the splash screen so the user won't come back when it presses back key

                finish();
                // start the home screen

                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Home.class);
                SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);

            }

        }, 2000); // time in milliseconds (1 second = 1000 milliseconds) until the run() method will be called

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

usually, when you create a splash screen it's a fully fledged `Activity` that is in charge of showing some UI.

what you should probably do is create a new class that extends `Activity` and runs your con from within its `onCreate` method.

after this, you should change you manifest file to have the activity defined as the launcher like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```